# Business logic validation patterns & advices

Tags: java, spring, validation, design-patterns

I have two layers of validation in my application. First is entity validation performed by bean validation API (e.g. required fields).
The second level is business logic validation. For example, user has a post. User can delete a post only if he is a creator of this post and post rating < 50. So I have to do something like this:

```
if (post.getCreator().equals(session.getUser())) {
  if (post.getRating() < 50) {
    postRepository.delete(post);
  } else errors.add(400, "Cant delete post with rating 50 or higher")
} else errors add (400, "You should be owner of the post")
```

I don't like this way as this conditionals are reused and I have to duplicate code. Moreover, if number of conditionals is greater than 5 or so it becomes unreal to read and understand the code.

Moreover, standard Spring Validator won't be very helpful as I have to maker different validation for one entity on different actions (delete and update for example)

So I'm looking for a way to do this in a smarter way (pattern maybe) and I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [the strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Each condition can be modelled as a function that takes a post and a session context and might return an error:

```
Post -> Session -> Optional<String>
```

You could represent this with an interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ValidationCondition {

    Optional<String> validate(final Post post, final Session session);
}
```

So for example:

```
public class CreatorValidation implements ValidationCondition {
    
    public Optional<String> validate(final Post post, final Session session) {
        if (post.getCreator().equals(session.getUser()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of("You should be the owner of the post");
    }
}
```

You can then store every validation in a list:

```
final List<ValidationCondition> conditions = new ArrayList<>();

conditions.add(new CreatorValidation());
conditions.add(new ScoreValidation());
// etc.
```

Using the list, validations can be applied in bulk:

```
final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();

for (final ValidationCondition condition : conditions) {
    final Optional<String> error = condition.validate(post, session);
    if (error.isPresent()) {
        errors.add(error.get());
    }
}
```

Using Java 8 lambdas, you could declare these inline:

```
final ValidationCondition condition = (post, session) -> {
    // Custom logic
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Strategy pattern is the solution in my opinion.
I will give you a very simple example. Lets say we have two kinds of credit cards, Visa and Mastercard. The logic to perform payment operation is the same for both cards, but card number validation is different. So, by passing VisaStrategy object through a workflow does the same logic and operations as we would pass MastercardStrategy, except one thing - card number validation, which is done inside each defined Strategy class, so you do not have any "if else" stuff in your code at all. Each Strategy class is now responsible for one and only one type of card validation.
If you look for flexible and easy to maintain code structure - use Strategy design pattern.

Comment: What if the parameters of validation method varies by condition? Lets say Visa cardnumber is an integer and also has a 4 digit code, but master card number is a one 16 digit number?